# Testing regular expressions algorithmically

Tags: algorithms, automata, regular-expressions

Is it possible to  test algorithmically whether the language of a given automaton is empty?

If I have a language L, could I say that L intersection with the empty set is L?

Comment: Hint about the DFA part. Think of it as a graph problem. A $L_{dfa}$ is not empty if and only if a certain condition is  valid. Said condition involves a small  subset of all possible states.

Comment: You are asking two questions. The answer to your second question is: $L \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Comment: Your title mentions regular expressions, your question mentions automata. Which are you after?

Comment: 1. Please ask only one question per question.  You are asking two different questions, and that doesn't work well for this site format.  You should post each question separately.  2. What have you tried?  We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it's usually helpful if you write your thoughts and what you could not figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Check whether there is a path from the starting state to some accepting state.